# Edit backend translations from extensions (news) safely for updates in typo3 6.x

Tags: translation, typo3, backend, typoscript

i tell me the question, to customize any backend translations from the news (tx_news) extension. Normally, i can edit the locallang_db.xlf file, found in ext/news/Resources/Private/Language, but is this method not secure for updates.

I want to edit some label translations from the news ext. and i imagine, that i copy this original language file into an other path, for example in a new ext. named my_custom_languages or in the fileadmin folder. But i don't know, who can i say the backend and the news ext. to use this file in the new path for translate any labels.

I hope you know what i mean :)

Greeting,
Olli

Answer (score 0):

The classic way is via Typoscript,

plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.de {
  more = mehr
}

if it shouldn't work, have a look at https://www.mail-archive.com/typo3-german@lists.typo3.org/msg26069.html